# Connection lost to VPS While using iptables by default policy as DROP for INPUT, OUTPUT, FORWARD

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewall

I'am using iptables in many server's but now stuck with this issue while using default Policy as DROP.

Here is my rules which i have used in VPS, Tried many time's everything seems fine but VPS getting disconnected when i use this rules.

Only i want ssh port 2222, and ntp for updating my time.

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --sport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --sport 123 -m state --state ,NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 123 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 10/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
```

till logout from VPS i can access VPS it's still established, If once i used to logout and trying to login again i can't login. Will any one review the rules for me ?

Comment: I think you mixed up sport and dport

Comment: Please don't think confirm it, I have not found any mistake from my rules so only im asking you

Comment: @miniBill i have fixed the issue as your pointing by replacing INPUT to dport and OUTPUT to sport, Thanks mate.. Above i have submitted my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

miniBill is right: you have indeed mixed up `sport` and `dport`.  When you write:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Your `INPUT` ssh traffic is **to** your server, so that should have **destination** port 2222, not **source** port; the `OUTPUT` traffic has the same problem.  Change those lines to

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 2222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

and things should work better.

Comment: Just now i have fixed it